# Do we have a way to install packages in self-defined folder while use existing packages

Tags: python, pip

My company has folder pylib installed hundreds of useful packages.

I want to install my own packages in my own folder myfolder
Since I don't have the rights to modify pylib folder

I want to install a package/module say mypkg in myfolder

but it depends on numpy >= 1.14.0

Say our system already have numpy 1.15.0 in folder pylib

Do I need to reinstall the same module in myfolder?

or I just install mypkg in myfolder and it will automatically detect the numpy 1.15.0 in the system folder pylib?

I want mypkg just use the one already installed, but it seems if I want to install mypkg in myfolder, it will have to install all the dependencies else there is an error and it could not get finished.

Is there a way to let the installation complete without install the package:numpy in myfolder?

Comment: `virtualenv --system-site-packages` ?